# When clicking the 'like' button in Facebook, Firefox prompts to download like.php

Tags: macos, firefox, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Some websites prompt to download PHP script after some time, but only in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/203015/some-websites-prompt-to-download-php-script-after-some-time-but-only-in-firefox)

A friend of mine uses OS X Lion with Firefox 7.0.1.

Sometimes, when he clicks on the 'like' button on Facebook, there will be a pop-up prompt asking to download `like.php`. This only happens on Facebook itself, not on any of the sites that implement the 'like' button.

A quick Google search indicated that this problem is also found on Windows.

Comment: Does this happen on Facebook only? Or on other sites including the Facebook "like" button? Which browser is it?

Comment: Hi, this happens only on Facebook. Firefox browser.

Comment: Also, the version is up-to-date: 7.0.1.

Comment: I edited your question to include that. In the future, you can also do that by clicking [edit] below your question, if you have any new information.